# Log disk write activity of a process

Tags: windows, hard-drive, logging, monitoring

Is there a program that allows me to log/monitor/view the disk write activity of a process?
For example, it would be able to log all files on disk that the process has created/modified.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).  Filter out everything except write activity by making two filters as follows:

1. `Operation` `begins with` `WriteFile` `Include`
2. `Operation` `begins with` `WriteConfig` `Include`

Comment: What is WriteConfig?