# Logging HDD Read/Write activity

Tags: hard-drive, disk-activity

Windows 8.0 - Acer i5 laptop, wifi to Modem/Router and Internet.

I just went to make some coffee and when I came back (about 10-mins) the hard drive light was flashing like crazy. I moved the mouse and it kept going but as soon as I clicked, it stopped instantly. I then didn't touch the mouse or keyboard and after 5-minutes it started flashing again. Stopped again with another click.

Now, not wanting to sound too paranoid, is there a way I can log what applications are using the HDD? Plus if they are reading or writing to it?

I looked at Process Monitor at this link, [Log disk write activity of a process](https://superuser.com/questions/618612/log-disk-write-activity-of-a-process)

But it is way out of my league understanding what is going on and how to set up the filter to just show disk activity. I'd just like to see what is writing or reading the disk during those times.

Comment: When you see this have a look at the Action Center icon. If it displays a clock sign, then the computer is running Scheduled Maintenance.

Comment: Maybe it's some Anti-Virus  - try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does indexing in full swing when the computer is relatively free and slows it down as soon as it detects user activity (mouse move or any such activity).
Search for "Indexing Options" in start menu it will show you the indexing activity.